# Add PNG with transparency to the PDF with Image()

Tags: php, tcpdf

I want to add a PNG image with transparency (a logo) over the background image (cover mode) of my TCPDF generated document but i'm getting the transparent part of the logo filled with white color instead.
Here's the code line :

`$pdf->Image('logo.png', 50, 50, 100, '', '', '', '', false, 300);`

I've tried to make the PNG transparency work by installing the imagick lib and using it instead of the GD lib. Unfortunately, this didn't work (replaced the white filling color by a black color). I installed the lib with those two command lines :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Thanks for the help